# Specify a dir subdirectory from within a zip file without extracting in Windows CMD

Tags: python, cmd, directory, zip, arelle

If i am running a program (in this case [arelle](http://arelle.org/)) from the GUI and if i want to open a zip **that contains a subdirectory with subfolders** the program opens a userform after i choose the zip file prompting me to choose a subfolder from inside the zip.

You can see what i mean below...

At first we choose a zip folder for our program to parse

[image]

And here we have the userform with the subdirectory where we can choose a folder from inside the zip
[image]

When i want to run the same program **from the `cmd`** how can i choose a subfolder from the subdirectory?

Here is the command that i use to parse the zip when running from source. However it throws an error due to the existence of a subdirectory inside the zip. What can i do to choose as i choose when i used the GUI edition of the program?

```
C:\>python arelleCmdLine.py -f C:\Python33\sec\2010\03\0000002809-0001047469-10-
002778-xbrl.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

All that needs to be done is this:

```
INITIAL PARADIGM CHOOSING A WHOLE BLOCK OF ZIP FILE WITH SUBFOLDERS IN IT'S DIR

C:\>python arelleCmdLine.py -f C:\Python33\sec\2010\03\0000002809-0001047469-10-
002778-xbrl.zip

SPECIFY A DIR SUBDIRECTORY FROM WITHIN A ZIP FILE WITHOUT EXTRACTING
```

If inside the zip file we have `1.xml` all you need to do is just:

```
C:\>python arelleCmdLine.py -f C:\Python33\sec\2010\03\0000002809-0001047469-10-
    002778-xbrl.zip/1.xml
```